# Sencha Architect Calling function from other function

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I have a FormPanel (See below) that has several functions defined.
I need to call one function from another function, but I get error that
the function I am calling is undefined.
If I call the ShowInspections from the OnMyButtonTap function it works
If I call the ShowInspections from the LoginOk function it DOES NOT work
I am at a loss I believe it is a scope issue, but so new it Sencha I really need
some help.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.LoginPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.Login',

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            height: 226,
            width: 440,
            title: 'Enter Login Information',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id: 'userid',
                    label: 'User ID',
                    labelWidth: '40%',
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id: 'pswd',
                    label: 'Password',
                    labelWidth: '40%',
                    required: true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            height: 86,
            itemId: 'mybutton',
            text: 'Login'
        }
    ],
    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMybuttonTap',
            event: 'tap',
            delegate: '#mybutton'
        }
    ]
},

onMybuttonTap: function(button, e, options) {
    doLogin(Ext.getCmp('userid').getValue(),Ext.getCmp('pswd').getValue(),this.LoginOk,this.LoginFail,this.LoginError);

},

LoginOk: function() {
    //
    // this function is called from doLogin and it works
    //
    //GetInspections('01/01/2011','12/31/2012','','',this.ShowInspections,this.LoadDataFail,this.LoadDataError);
    // the function GetInspections does work, but does not call the "ShowInspections" function
    this.ShowInspection);  // directly calling this function does NOT work either
},

LoginFail: function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Invalid User ID and/or Password.');

},

LoginError: function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Login Error!');
},

LoadDataFail: function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('No Inspections found.');
},

LoadDataError: function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Error Loading Inspections.');
},

ShowInspections: function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('got inspections');
}
```

});

Comment: Am I crazy, or does the example code not even feature a function named GetInspections?

Answer (score 0):

There is some typo in the current code.

```
this.ShowInspection);
```

should read as

```
this.ShowInspections();
```

Isn't that your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed () everywhere you just need to change as this.LoginOk(), this.LoginFail() etc and this.ShowInspections()